# How to use property in dynamic class if i know the name of it

Tags: c#, dynamic

I need to change the string that the client sends to the values ​​from the class property.

At the moment, it works for me until I get a class that does not support the following entry:

Working example (we start from the payout class):

The customer sends:
"Employee.Name" in string

My code:

```
List <string> parametrs = ClientTxT.Split('.'). ToList();
dynamic MyDynamicObject = payout;
for (int y = 0; y <parametrs.Count; y ++)
    MyDynamicObject = MyDynamicObject [parametrs [y], RowVersion.Current];
```

I enter the Employee and take the Name property. 
Everything is OK because the Employee class is compatible with this entry:

```
object ObjectIRecived = myClass[propertyNameInString, RowVersion];
```

Example not working:
I have a problem when the class is not compatible with this entry, e.g. Number.
The Number class has only two property: "Full" and "Simple".

If the customer sends "Number.Full" I got an error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
  HResult = 0x80131500
  Message = Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Soneta.Core.CoreModule.NumerDokumentuRecord'
  Source = <Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

My guess is that in this case I have to refer directly to Number.Full but I don't know how to do it in the code, since the propertyname is in string

Comment: Can't you just store the data in a Dictionary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Okey, it was Field not a Property for some reason. Your link worked, buyt had to change property to field.